# How to convert a value to a type that is passed as a parameter

Tags: c#, database

I have a function that will execute aggregated function `(ie. COUNT(),MIN(), MAX())`

sometimes I want to return `int, double, date, datetime....`

I'm having an issue trying to convert the return value

the following line is giving me an error `value = Convert.ChangeType(vv, typeof(T) );`

Here is the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is my method

```
public T getValue<T>(string query, List<MySqlParameter> pars)
{
    T value;
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        if (pars != null)
        {
            foreach (MySqlParameter p in pars)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
        }

        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            object vv = (T)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (vv != null)
            {
                value = Convert.ChangeType(vv, typeof(T) );
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){

            Common.Alert(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error");
            value = default(T);

        } finally {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

And when I use this method I use this

```
int cnt = db.getValue<int>(query, params);
```

Comment: Overall, this seems a bit dangerous... for example, you can ask for an int but the database stores it as a long. You should get the method caller to convert/cast the value themselves, and have your method return the same type as supported in the table.

Comment: but count will always return int, depending of the type of the collumn I will pass the correct type. so If I was to check the max of a double column then I can do this `double cnt = db.getValue<double>(query, params);` etc. However, I am open to a better approach Please give me a corrected method in an answer

Comment: The error message you see is meaningful. Check the return type of `ChangeType`. Read the error message. You're storing an object in a variable of type T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. First you cast to `T`, then if it's not null, you convert it to `T`? The conversion is useless. I think it's worth pointing out that the particular error you're getting ("Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'.") is because [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) returns an `object`, so it's often casted immediately after calling:

```
value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(v, typeof(T));
```

In your case, you might want to do this:

```
object rawValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(rawValue, typeof(T));
```

Note that if `rawValue` is `null` and `T` is a value type (`struct`, e.g. `int`), this (portion of) code will throw an exception. This is probably better than silently letting the value be `default(T)`.